# Weighting Stats and Plots in Pandas Profiling

Tags: python, pandas, weighted, pandas-profiling

I have a column named "weight" in a pandas dataframe. Is there a method or way to use this column to weight all other columns when generating a pandas profiling report? I want to maintain the original values for sample count, min/max, etc. while also taking into account the weighted data.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.